# Move large data between tables in oracle with bulk insert

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle11g, bulkinsert

I want to move 1 million rows of data to another table.  Im using query:

```
insert into Table1
select * from Table2;
```

in my PL/SQL function. But this way is too slow.

How can I do this with **Bulk Insert** method?

- Source and destination table has same structure.
- Tables have hash partition and 1 index.

Comment: Have you disabled constraints and indexes on the target table during the insert?

Comment: No, I didnt. Do I need to?

Comment: Updating the indexes row by row is much slower than rebuilding them afterwards.

Comment: @Klas thanks. Im getting error when disable and enable index. ORA-14086: a partitioned index may not be rebuilt as a whole

Comment: ALTER INDEX PK_SUBS_FREE unusable; and then, ALTER INDEX PK_SUBS_FREE rebuild;

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Forget about bulk insert. Because the insert into select is the best bulk you can load.
The fastest would be to disable the indexes (mark them unusable) and do this in a SINGLE 
insert:

```
insert /*+ append */ into TARGET
select COLS
  from SOURCE;

commit;
```

and rebuild the indexes using UNRECOVERABLE (and maybe even parallel).

**PS:** If the table is partitioned (Both source and target, you can even use parallel inserts)

**FOLLOW UP:**

Check the performance of the below select

```
SELECT    /*+ PARALLEL(A 4)
            USE_HASH(A) ORDERED */
      YOUR_COLS
FROM
      YOUR_TABLE A
WHERE
      ALL_CONDITIONS;
```

If faster then

```
INSERT   /*+ APPEND */
     INTO
      TARGET
    SELECT /*+ PARALLEL(A 4)
            USE_HASH(A) ORDERED */
          YOUR_COLS
    FROM
          YOUR_TABLE A
    WHERE
          ALL_CONDITIONS;
```

Comment: Tables have hash partition and 1 index. How can I do parallel insert.

Comment: keep in mind that there will not be a big improvement if the new table is being written into a newly created Tablespace. Because there is no use in APPEND for a fresh TBS.

Comment: I agree that a single insert is the way to go.  And using [direct-path inserts](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e25494/tables.htm#ADMIN01509) may significantly improve performance (but remember that your data will not be recoverable until the next backup!).  NOLOGGING should be used instead of the deprecated UNRECOVERABLE, parallelism does not require partitioning, and the USE_HASH and ORDERED hints will not do anything.

Comment: @jonearles I agree on NOLOGGING. But for USE_HASH, I tried to spread equivalent amount of data on all parallel select. Are you sure it wont work?

Comment: [USE_HASH](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/sql_elements006.htm#SQLRF50703) is meant to force a hash join.  If the SELECT really only has one table then there is no join method.  Oracle will automatically try to evenly distribute the data through block range granules.

Answer (score 1):

USING Bulk Collect

Converting to collections and bulk processing can increase the volume and complexity of your code. If you need a serious boost in performance, however, that increase is well-justified.

Collections, an evolution of PL/SQL tables that allows us to manipulate many variables at once, as a unit. Collections, coupled with two new features introduced with Oracle 8i, BULK_COLLECT and FORALL, can dramatically increase the performance of data manipulation code within PL/SQL.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE test_proc (p_array_size IN PLS_INTEGER DEFAULT 100)
IS
TYPE ARRAY IS TABLE OF all_objects%ROWTYPE;
l_data ARRAY;

CURSOR c IS SELECT * FROM all_objects;

BEGIN
    OPEN c;
    LOOP
    FETCH c BULK COLLECT INTO l_data LIMIT p_array_size;

    FORALL i IN 1..l_data.COUNT
    INSERT INTO t1 VALUES l_data(i);

    EXIT WHEN c%NOTFOUND;
    END LOOP;
    CLOSE c;
END test_proc;
```

Answer (score 0):

this procedure created by rohit sahani......
**using bulk collect i create this procedure
in this procedure i also did update and insert in table  and
in this procedure i did collect data in bulk and then update in salary with the use of forall statement .**

CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE sam_proc_1(l_salary  NUMBER)
IS
l_address VARCHAR(100) := 'karnatka';
a_address  VARCHAR(100) := 'bihar';

```
c_limit PLS_INTEGER := 100;

TYPE employee_ids_t IS TABLE OF  emp.emp_id%TYPE;
 l_employee_ids   employee_ids_t;
       
    CURSOR employees_cur IS SELECT emp_id FROM emp;        
   -- CURSOR CUR1 IS SELECT EMP_ID, FNAME, ADDRESS FROM EMP;
    BEGIN
       OPEN employees_cur;
       LOOP
          FETCH employees_cur BULK COLLECT INTO l_employee_ids LIMIT c_limit;
          EXIT WHEN l_employee_ids.COUNT = 0;
          -----here start updating
        FORALL indx IN 1 .. l_employee_ids.COUNT SAVE EXCEPTIONS
          UPDATE emp a
           SET a.salary = a.salary + l_salary
           WHERE a.emp_id = l_employee_ids(indx);
      commit;
      END LOOP;
      -----------
      BEGIN
        UPDATE emp v 
           SET v.address = l_address
          WHERE v.address = a_address;
          COMMIT;
          EXCEPTION WHEN
            OTHERS THEN
             RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20001,'An error encountered while updating in address - '
              ||SQLCODE||' -ERROR- '||SQLERRM);
        END;
     ---------
     BEGIN
       FOR I IN ( SELECT EMP_ID, FNAME, ADDRESS FROM EMP)
         LOOP
           INSERT INTO students
           ( stu_id, stu_name, stu_address)
           VALUES
           (i.emp_id, i.fname, i.address);
         END LOOP;
         COMMIT;
            EXCEPTION WHEN
             OTHERS THEN
              RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20001,'An error encountered while inserting - '
              ||SQLCODE||' -ERROR- '||SQLERRM); 
       END;
     ------------
   EXCEPTION
       WHEN OTHERS
       THEN
          IF SQLCODE = -24381
          THEN
             FOR indx IN 1 .. SQL%BULK_EXCEPTIONS.COUNT
             LOOP
                 -- Caputring errors occured during update
                DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line( SQL%BULK_EXCEPTIONS (indx).ERROR_INDEX
                ||','||
                SQL%BULK_EXCEPTIONS (indx).ERROR_CODE);
                 --<You can inset the error records to a table here>
             END LOOP;
          ELSE
             RAISE;
          END IF;
    END sam_proc_1;
    -----END PROCEDURE;c
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32044273)